# How can I identify two different connections to sockets using python?

Tags: python, sockets

I looked around first but couldn't find anything to answer my question.

The problem is that I was making a little chat program. And after watching a few tutorials and following some documentation I managed to make a chat program that works like such:

I've got a client and a client/server. The client/server basically sets itself up as server and can also reply to the client.

So it listens on a certain port the user identifies and then accepts the clients connection.

The problem is that I decided I wanted to switch this all up a bit.

Rather than having a client/server. I want two clients and a server that acts as a switchboard between both clients. Essentially directing all chat to the connected addresses.

Here's where I am a little stumped:

```
HOST = input("Please define the host IP, if over local, name 'localhost': ")
PORT = int(input("Please define the port to be communicated over: "))
if PORT == False:
    PORT = 4010


s = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)#AF_INET and SOCK_STREAM are standard. 
s.bind((HOST,PORT))# The socket is being bound, or assigned, the ip of the server, as well as the communicating port.
s.listen(2)#Accepting only a single connection. EDIT: Now two connections.
conn,addr = s.accept()


print("\nNetwork activity from address: ",addr,)

# Section two: Communications Loop.
```

The problem is that `s.listen(2)` has been edited to take 2 connections, but how am I supposed to manage different connections connecting, or assign them variables so that I can get the switchboard thing to work?

If you've found this as a duplicate thread, please post the link and I'll see if I can delete this one and go read there first. (Sorry, I've had terrible experience posting before here, (voted down for reasons I don't get))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The listen parameter tells you how many connection can be pending, not how many will be accepted.

You must use the select module, which allows you to insert a list of file descriptors and check which ones are ready for input or for output.

Then you would have a list of open connections (initially empty), plus the socket s, to pass to select, then you should read the data, write it to all the other connections, and loop forever.

```
import select

connections = []

while True:
    rlist,wlist,xlist = select.select(connections + [s],[],[])
    for i in rlist:
        if i == s:
            conn,addr = s.accept()
            connections.append(conn)
            continue
        data = i.recv(1024)
        for q in connections:
            if q != i and q != s:
                q.send(data)
```

This code doesn't take into account complications of using non-blocking mode, so one slow client will slow down all the other clients too, but in general it should work.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea how to execute this. Any tutorials, or documentation you can point me towards that entails what I need to do it?

Comment: Eugh. A little confused about how this works. It appears you start with a list called connections that is initially empty. (Because we have no connections) You then have a continuous loop that does the following:  Waiting readables, waiting writeables, and waiting exceptional conditions are all going to be as follows: Waiting Readable is going to be [s] because your waiting on our listening socket for incoming data. And the other two are empty. Now what I am confused about is what 'i' is, and how the rest works.

Comment: Do you think you could show me how to add or identify two different addresses's? And so I would have like Address P and Address Q, and if I recieve data from address P, then I sent it to Q, using if functions?

Comment: That's what i did, and it works with any number of connections, not just 2.

Comment: I'm just sort of stupid. Sorry, I'll go about trying to understand it instead.

Comment: sorry, but what does   i   represent, and q?  That's what is really stumping me